# Print diamond knowing length and width (Python)

Tags: python, space

I need to print a diamond using python, by entering the length. I already made it to work for checking the width depending if it is odd or even, also making sure the number that is input is correct. But I got a problem when it prints the result.
Here is what I get :

```
length : 10

    *
    ***
    *****
    *******
    *********
    *********
    *******
    *****
    ***
    *


length = 10   #This line don't exist normally, its just to avoid the input and every check.
lengthTest = length
answer = lengthTest % 2
if (answer == 0):
    length_1 = 1
    while (length_1 < length):
        print("*" * length_1)
        length_1 = length_1 + 2
    length_1 = length_1 - 2
    while (length_1 > 0):
        print("*" * length_1)
        length_1 = length_1 - 2

else:
    print("odd")
```

Any solution to the space problem to make its actually look like a diamond?

Comment: Well yeah, you're only ever printing stars, but you'll also need some `print(" " * lenght_space)` code to print some spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother with multiple for loops?

```
for i in range(-n + 1, n):
    print('{:^{}}'.format('*' * ((n - abs(i)) * 2 - 1), n * 2 - 1))
```

- If you want half size, set `n = n // 2` before the loop.

---

#### Here is the math:

Every time we get `+2` asterisks, and we want them rising until we hit the center and descending afterwards, so we iterate from `-n+1` to `n-1` and calculate the number of the asterisks by `n` minus the absolute current index (to provide reverse symmetry between `[-n, -1]` and `[1, n]`) multiplied by two, minus one to create a center-able diamond (odd lengths).

We center it with string formatting using `^{}` with `n * 2 - 1`, because that is the highest possible width (when `i = 0`, `(n - abs(i)) * 2 - 1` would be `n * 2 - 1`).

**Outputs** (for `n = 5`):

```
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
 ******* 
  *****  
   ***   
    *
```

Comment: I was looking to print a diamond using the middle length, not the side 1, sorry if my message was not specific enought :) Thanks for helping out tho!

Comment: @MaxyArthes did you see my comment about `n = n // 2`?

Answer (score 1):

Print spaces before stars:

```
length = 10
x = 1
while x < length:
    print(" " * ((length - x) // 2), "*" * x)
    x += 2
x -= 2
while x > 0:
    print(" " * ((length - x) // 2), "*" * x)
    x -= 2
```

**Output**

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```

Comment: you beat me by 10s :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add add half of `length-length_1` spaces to the front:

```
length = 10   #This line don't exist normally, its just to avoid the input and every check.
lengthTest = length
answer = lengthTest % 2
if (answer == 0):
    length_1 = 1
    while (length_1 < length):
        print(" " * ((length - length_1)//2) + "*" * length_1)
        length_1 = length_1 + 2
    length_1 = length_1 - 2
    while (length_1 > 0):
        print(" " * ((length - length_1) // 2) + "*" * length_1)
        length_1 = length_1 - 2

else:
    print("odd")
```