# How to print ascii diamonds having two same lines at the center?

Tags: python, ascii-art

The user input represents half of the rows in the diamonds (top triangles). If I enter the input as 9, I should have 9 rows including the center/longest line. But, underneath I only have 8 lines (I need to have 9 on the bottom too, including a copy of the line above so it’s even). I need to make it so that both of my bottom triangles also have that repeated line so there are two lines at the center having same number of asterisks. I think I insert it below my last printed line but it doesn’t work.

My question is:  How can I have two center lines that are the same?

```
rows = int(input("Please enter the amount of rows in half of the diamond:"))

#Upper triangles 1 and 2
for i in range(rows):
#spaces for triangle 1
for s in range(rows - i) :
    print(" ", end="")
#stars
for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
    print("*", end="")
    
 #space to separate triangle 1 and 2
   for s in range(rows-i+1) :
      print(" ", end="")

   #spaces for triangle 2
    for s in range (i,rows) :
       print(end=" ")
      #stars
      for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
        print()

#new for loop under middle line: stars, how many spaces? 

#Lower triangles 3 and 4
  for i in range(rows,0,-1):
   #spaces for triangle 3
   for s in range(rows - i) :
     print(" ", end="")
    
#stars
for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
    print("*", end="")

 #space to separate triangle 3 and 4
   for s in range(rows-i+1) :
     print(" ", end="")

#spaces for triangle 4
for s in range(rows - i) :
    print(" ", end="")
#stars
for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
    print("*", end="")
 print()


if rows<=0:
    print("Invalid.")
```

Answer (score 1):

This version reduces a lot of duplication. I modified it to output a selectable number of diamonds:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
rows = int(input("Please enter the amount of rows in half of the diamond: "))
diamonds = int(input("Please enter the number of diamonds: "))
for row in list(range(rows)) + list(range(rows - 1, -1, -1)):
    spacers = 1 # leading space "wedge"
    for diamond in range(diamonds):
        print(" " * (rows - row) * (spacers), end = "")
        print("*" * (row * 2 + 1), end = "")
        spacers = 2 # intervening space wedges
    print()
```

```
Please enter the amount of rows in half of the diamond: 5
Please enter the number of diamonds: 6
     *          *          *          *          *          *
    ***        ***        ***        ***        ***        ***
   *****      *****      *****      *****      *****      *****
  *******    *******    *******    *******    *******    *******
 *********  *********  *********  *********  *********  *********
 *********  *********  *********  *********  *********  *********
  *******    *******    *******    *******    *******    *******
   *****      *****      *****      *****      *****      *****
    ***        ***        ***        ***        ***        ***
     *          *          *          *          *          *
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to repeat the last row in the output change the range of the first loop to:

```
for i in range(1,rows+1):
```

This answers already sufficiently your question.

---

---

Below some add-on information and code helping to develop better programming skills.

The first step in improving the code can be to notice that Python comes with the possibility of adding strings to each other and with the possibility to multiply a string with an integer number N to obtain a resulting string being N-times repeated. Using this possibilities the code shrinks to:

```
rows = 9 # int(input("Please enter the amount of rows in half of the diamond:"))
for i in range(1,rows+1):      # Upper triangles 1 and 2
    print(" "*(rows-i)       + # spaces for triangle 1
          "*"*(i*2-1)        + # stars
          " "*(2*(rows-i)+1) + # space to separate triangle 1 and 2
          "*"*(i*2-1)          # stars       
         )
for i in range(rows,0,-1):     # Lower triangles 3 and 4
    print(" "*(rows-i)       + # spaces for triangle 1
          "*"*(i*2-1)        + # stars
          " "*(2*(rows-i)+1) + # space to separate triangle 1 and 2
          "*"*(i*2-1)          # stars       
         )
```

printing:

```
        *                 *
       ***               ***
      *****             *****
     *******           *******
    *********         *********
   ***********       ***********
  *************     *************
 ***************   ***************
***************** *****************
***************** *****************
 ***************   ***************
  *************     *************
   ***********       ***********
    *********         *********
     *******           *******
      *****             *****
       ***               ***
        *                 *
```

The next step is to notice that there is repetition of same code blocks in the code above and use a Python list to store the lines in order to eliminate this repetition.

The code below uses list comprehension to create a list of lines for the upper half of the diamond and then prints the list along with its reversed version being the lower part of the diamonds. In the print statement an asterisk `*` is used for expanding a list to function parameters where the `sep='\n'` (standard value is `' '` space) option in the print command prints each passed parameter in a new line:

```
lst_lines = [ (" "*(rows-i)       + # spaces for triangle 1
               "*"*(i*2-1)        + # stars
               " "*(2*(rows-i)+1) + # space to separate triangle 1 and 2
               "*"*(i*2-1)          # stars       
              ) for i in range(1, rows) ]
print(*lst_lines, *reversed(lst_lines), sep='\n')
```

Next step could be to notice that it is sufficient to have only the pattern of the upper left half of a diamond in order to have all what is necessary to arrange the strings for print. Using a list comprehension and appropriate slicing reduces the code necessary to print the required output to:

```
hd = [ (rows-i)*" "+(i*"*") for i in range(1, rows+1)] #  left half of upper half of diamond
ll = [s+s[-2::-1]+'  '+s+s[-2::-1] for s in hd] # upper lines diamonds
print(*ll, *ll[::-1]), sep='\n')
```

Next step would be to discover that there are f-strings in Python for creating formatted strings with specified width and the possibility of centering the position of the formatted string within the required length. This can be done using formatting specification `^{2*r-1}` where `2*r-1` is the required string width and usage of `^` positions the asterisk(s) in the center of the resulting string.

Making use of the feature described above makes writing code for printing diamonds easy and requiring very small amount of code. A side-effect of using this method is that it is possible without any additional code to specify the number of diamonds printed next to each other. The code below:

```
n = 6
r = 5
ll=[n*f'{"*"*(2*i-1):^{2*r-1}}  ' for i in range(1,r+1)]
print(*ll,*ll[::-1],sep='\n')
```

prints:

```
    *          *          *          *          *          *      
   ***        ***        ***        ***        ***        ***     
  *****      *****      *****      *****      *****      *****    
 *******    *******    *******    *******    *******    *******   
*********  *********  *********  *********  *********  *********  
*********  *********  *********  *********  *********  *********  
 *******    *******    *******    *******    *******    *******   
  *****      *****      *****      *****      *****      *****    
   ***        ***        ***        ***        ***        ***     
    *          *          *          *          *          *
```

See the other answer for code using only the feature of multiplication of a string with an integer requiring two loops and much more code to achieve the same result.

---

---

For the sake of completeness below also the entire but correct formatted code from your question printing the diamonds as requested:

```
rows = 9 # int(input("Please enter the amount of rows in half of the diamond:"))
#Upper triangles 1 and 2
for i in range(1, rows+1):
    #spaces for triangle 1
    for s in range(rows - i) :
        print(" ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")
   
    #space to separate triangle 1 and 2
    for s in range(rows-i+1) :
        print(" ", end="")

    #spaces for triangle 2
    for s in range (i, rows) :
       print("", end=" ")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")

    #new for loop under middle line: stars, how many spaces? 
    print()

#Lower triangles 3 and 4
for i in range(rows, 0, -1):
    #spaces for triangle 3
    for s in range(rows - i) :
        print(" ", end="")
    
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")

    #space to separate triangle 3 and 4
    for s in range(rows-i+1) :
        print(" ", end="")

    #spaces for triangle 4
    for s in range(rows - i) :
        print(" ", end="")
    #stars
    for stars in range((i * 2) - 1):
        print("*", end="")

    print()

if rows<=0:
    print("Invalid.")
```

The conclusion of all the said above is that it is worth it to learn as much about the features of the used programming language as possible. It can make your life 25 times easier making it possible to achieve with only two (2) lines of code the same result as with fifty (50).

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you for maintaining this in my code. I had an idea of what to do, but it wasn't clear enough. Thank you so much once again!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted to make the question marked as answered.

Comment: And check out latest update to my answer for a very short version of code printing the requested result.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple questions and answers here on stackoverflow which mostly don't exactly cover the case of this question here (don't cover multiple diamonds and/or don't cover two same lines at the diamonds center), but provide some interesting other aspects of printing ascii art diamonds:

- [Print diamond knowing length and width (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881550/print-diamond-knowing-length-and-width-python)
- [print a diamond of numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447602/print-a-diamond-of-numbers-in-python)
- [How to print this diamond pattern using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61363967/how-to-print-this-diamond-pattern-using-python)
- [Printing Simple Diamond Pattern in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548099/printing-simple-diamond-pattern-in-python)

The following question:

- [dual diamond structure using nested repetition structures in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853521/dual-diamond-structure-using-nested-repetition-structures-in-python-3)
  is an exact duplicate of the above, but the given answers don't mention the string formatting approach (see my another answer) which is the best approach in Python known to me at the moment.

---

---

The function below tries to provide code able to cover most of the various cases as a kind of supplement to the other answers and a summary and reference about the subject to point to in case of duplicate questions:

```
def ascii_diamonds(no_of=7,rows=4,cstm_c='*',sharp=False,vers=0,with_space=False):
    assert no_of < 10 and rows < 10 and 0 <= vers <= 3
    c = cstm_c if cstm_c is not None else ['*','#','a',1][vers]
    l = None
    if   isinstance(c, int):
        if c > 9: 
            print('\n >>> int values > 9 are not supported <<< \n')
            returna
        if vers == 0: 
            l = [*(rows*str(c))]
        if vers == 1: 
            if 10-c >= rows: 
                l = [str(i) for i in range(c,10)]
    elif isinstance(c, str) and len(c)==1:
        abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstxyz'
        if vers == 0: 
            l = [*(rows*c)]
        if vers == 1 and c.lower() in abc:
            pos_c = [*abc].index(c.lower())
            if len(abc) >= pos_c + rows:
                if c.islower():  
                    l = [*abc[pos_c:]]
                else: 
                    l = [*abc.upper()[pos_c:]]
    elif isinstance(c, str) and len(c)>=rows:
        l = c

    def lr(i):
        if with_space:
            li = [' ']+[ s+' ' for s in l[i-1:i] ]*i
            return ''.join(li).strip()
        else:  
            li = l[0:i]
            return ''.join(li+li[::-1][1:])

    if l is None:
        print('\n >>> not supported parameter set <<< \n')
        return

    ll=[no_of*f'{lr(i):^{2*rows-1}}  ' for i in range(1,rows+1)]

    if sharp:
        print(*ll[:-1],*ll[::-1],sep='\n')
    else: 
        print(*ll,*ll[::-1],sep='\n')
```

The parameter `vers=` decides if a single number or letter is to use for the entire diamond (`vers=0`) or if it is to use as a start for building a sequence (`vers=1`) of same kind (digits or letters) within a diamond.

The parameter `sharp=` decides if the center of the diamond will be a single (`sharp=True`) or a double line (`sharp=False`).

The parameter `cstm_c=` can be any single character or an integer value up to 9 or a character sequence to use in the diamond pattern.

The parameter `with_space=` if set `True` prints the diamond with included spaces.

Below some examples of output when using the function:

```
ascii_diamonds(7,rows=4,cstm_c=0)
   0        0        0        0        0        0        0     
  000      000      000      000      000      000      000    
 00000    00000    00000    00000    00000    00000    00000   
0000000  0000000  0000000  0000000  0000000  0000000  0000000  
0000000  0000000  0000000  0000000  0000000  0000000  0000000  
 00000    00000    00000    00000    00000    00000    00000   
  000      000      000      000      000      000      000    
   0        0        0        0        0        0        0     

ascii_diamonds(7,rows=4,cstm_c=0,vers=1)
   0        0        0        0        0        0        0     
  010      010      010      010      010      010      010    
 01210    01210    01210    01210    01210    01210    01210   
0123210  0123210  0123210  0123210  0123210  0123210  0123210  
0123210  0123210  0123210  0123210  0123210  0123210  0123210  
 01210    01210    01210    01210    01210    01210    01210   
  010      010      010      010      010      010      010    
   0        0        0        0        0        0        0     

ascii_diamonds(7,rows=4,cstm_c=0,vers=1,with_space=True)
   0        0        0        0        0        0        0     
  1 1      1 1      1 1      1 1      1 1      1 1      1 1    
 2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2   
3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  
3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  3 3 3 3  
 2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2    2 2 2   
  1 1      1 1      1 1      1 1      1 1      1 1      1 1    
   0        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

```
ascii_diamonds(7,rows=4,cstm_c="#"   ,sharp=True ,with_space=True)
   #        #        #        #        #        #        #     
  # #      # #      # #      # #      # #      # #      # #    
 # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #   
# # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  
 # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #   
  # #      # #      # #      # #      # #      # #      # #    
   #        #        #        #        #        #        #     

ascii_diamonds(7,rows=4,cstm_c="@$&^",sharp=True)
   @        @        @        @        @        @        @     
  @$@      @$@      @$@      @$@      @$@      @$@      @$@    
 @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@   
@$&^&$@  @$&^&$@  @$&^&$@  @$&^&$@  @$&^&$@  @$&^&$@  @$&^&$@  
 @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@    @$&$@   
  @$@      @$@      @$@      @$@      @$@      @$@      @$@    
   @        @        @        @        @        @        @     

ascii_diamonds(7,rows=4,cstm_c="#"   ,sharp=False,with_space=True)
   #        #        #        #        #        #        #     
  # #      # #      # #      # #      # #      # #      # #    
 # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #   
# # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  
# # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  # # # #  
 # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #    # # #   
  # #      # #      # #      # #      # #      # #      # #    
   #        #        #        #        #        #        #
```

```
ascii_diamonds(7,rows=4,cstm_c="H",vers=1)
   H        H        H        H        H        H        H     
  HIH      HIH      HIH      HIH      HIH      HIH      HIH    
 HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH   
HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  
HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  HIJKJIH  
 HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH    HIJIH   
  HIH      HIH      HIH      HIH      HIH      HIH      HIH    
   H        H        H        H        H        H        H     

ascii_diamonds(7,rows=4,cstm_c="H",vers=1,with_space=True)
   H        H        H        H        H        H        H     
  I I      I I      I I      I I      I I      I I      I I    
 J J J    J J J    J J J    J J J    J J J    J J J    J J J   
K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  
K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  K K K K  
 J J J    J J J    J J J    J J J    J J J    J J J    J J J   
  I I      I I      I I      I I      I I      I I      I I    
   H        H        H        H        H        H        H     

ascii_diamonds(7,rows=4,cstm_c="H")
   H        H        H        H        H        H        H     
  HHH      HHH      HHH      HHH      HHH      HHH      HHH    
 HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH   
HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  
HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  HHHHHHH  
 HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH    HHHHH   
  HHH      HHH      HHH      HHH      HHH      HHH      HHH    
   H        H        H        H        H        H        H
```

```
ascii_diamonds(5,rows=5,cstm_c="W%|@$O^",sharp=True)
    W          W          W          W          W      
   W%W        W%W        W%W        W%W        W%W     
  W%|%W      W%|%W      W%|%W      W%|%W      W%|%W    
 W%|@|%W    W%|@|%W    W%|@|%W    W%|@|%W    W%|@|%W   
W%|@$@|%W  W%|@$@|%W  W%|@$@|%W  W%|@$@|%W  W%|@$@|%W  
 W%|@|%W    W%|@|%W    W%|@|%W    W%|@|%W    W%|@|%W   
  W%|%W      W%|%W      W%|%W      W%|%W      W%|%W    
   W%W        W%W        W%W        W%W        W%W     
    W          W          W          W          W      

ascii_diamonds(5,rows=5,cstm_c="@%|@$O^",sharp=False)
    @          @          @          @          @      
   @%@        @%@        @%@        @%@        @%@     
  @%|%@      @%|%@      @%|%@      @%|%@      @%|%@    
 @%|@|%@    @%|@|%@    @%|@|%@    @%|@|%@    @%|@|%@   
@%|@$@|%@  @%|@$@|%@  @%|@$@|%@  @%|@$@|%@  @%|@$@|%@  
@%|@$@|%@  @%|@$@|%@  @%|@$@|%@  @%|@$@|%@  @%|@$@|%@  
 @%|@|%@    @%|@|%@    @%|@|%@    @%|@|%@    @%|@|%@   
  @%|%@      @%|%@      @%|%@      @%|%@      @%|%@    
   @%@        @%@        @%@        @%@        @%@     
    @          @          @          @          @
```